# What do the golden puzzle pieces you get from the goat herder do?

Tags: icebreaker-viking-voyage

In Nitrome's latest Icebreaker game for iOS, there is a goat herder in some levels. If you manage to move all of the goats in those levels into his boat, you get a **golden puzzle piece** that moves to the top of the screen and stays there. Once you've completed the level, there is **no sign** that you ever collected one.

Is there any way to see **the number of puzzle pieces** you have collected? Is there **a certain use for them**, perhaps later in the game? They just seem to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from [this website](http://nitrome.wikia.com/wiki/Icebreaker:_A_Viking_Voyage) that the golden pieces are used in gaining access to other parts of maps:

> Completing sidequests gives a golden puzzle piece, granting access to another part of the map that is attached to that level. This part of the map is only accessible through the completion of this part of the sidequest.

You only seem to be able to collect only 1 at every point.

Comment: As it turns out, the first goat rescue grants access to an alternate path, and beyond that point the goats are needed to progress.